# How can I get the history of changes of a moved or deleted file in git?

Tags: git

## My situation

I have a git repo synced with github in my directory `~/my-repo`. I created some files, after a while make changes to them, after a while move them, then delete one.

I what see history of the changes of each of them (not needed to be with the same command at the same time).

## In detail

I made these changes. After each of them, I a run `git add`, `git commit` and `git push`. Between them I make hundreds of changes in other unrelated files.

1. I created two files `one.c` and `two.c` in `~/my-repo/app1/examples`.
2. I made changes in both `one.c` and `two.c`
3. I move (using git move) both to the folder `~/my-repo/app1/misc`.
4. I made other changes to both `one.c` and `two.c`
5. I deleted `two.c`

## My Questions

How I get all the changes of `~/my-repo/app1/misc/one.c` including the changes of the second point (made in `~/my-repo/app1/examples`)?

How I get all the changes of the former file `~/my-repo/app1/misc/two.c` including the changes of the second point (made in `~/my-repo/app1/examples`)?

Comment: Would `git log -p ~/my-repo/app1/misc/one.c` work? Or maybe `git diff ~/my-repo/app1/misc/one.c`? Are you concerned that history would be lost because you moved the file from `~/my-repo/app1/examples`? I don’t think that should be an issue; just check the history of the last location of a file and you should be good.

Comment: Use the `--follow` option to follow the file rename. E.g. `git log --follow -p -- app1/misc/one.c`